# PgAdmin 4. Unable to work under Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am new to PostgreSQL and I have installed Postgresql 12 version for win64 from EDB website.
After the installation I tried to use pgAdmin but I ran into some issues:

- With Internet Explorer I got this error "your browser was detected as Internet explorer 11. which is either deprecated or not supported by pgAdmin4"
- With Google Chrome I got this error. "The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

I did what many others told to do:

- Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration turned off.
- changed the PgAdmin default browser to chrome.
- Added my default PgAdmin server to Internet Security Trusted list.

Please help !

Comment: I suggest you don't use pgAdmin 4 in IE 11 as it's not the [supported browser](https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#11) of pgAdmin. I also try to test the [official demo](https://www.pgadmin.org/try/) in IE 11 and it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. There is not much information about IE11 not being supported anymore. All I can see is

> The following browsers are currently supported, but that support will
> cease in a future release of pgAdmin. It is strongly advised that a
> supported browser is used instead:
>
> Internet Explorer 11

https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/

The followings are supported

> Chrome 72
>
> Firefox 65+
>
> Edge 44+
>
> Safari 12+

I have installed Edge and set it as the default browser. Now everything works as expected.